# Secure WebSocket Connection through nginx 1.10.3 and LetsEncrypt

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, websocket

Been ripping hair out because I cannot find out why I cannot connect to my `WebSocket` server through `HTTPS`.

So, I have an Express 4 server running a `vue` app. It uses the `ws` library from npm to connect to the `WebSocket` server. The nginx is 1.10.3. I use LetsEncrypt to secure it.

When I go online, I get (in the console):

> main.js:12 WebSocket connection to 'wss://play.mysite.com:8443/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Line 12:

> window.ws = new WebSocket(`${tls}://${window.location.hostname}:${port}`);`

That is `wss://play.mysite.com:8443`. It is indeed on a subdomain.

Here is my `nginx` block:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
  root /var/www/play.mysite.com/;
  index index.html;

  access_log /var/log/wss-access-ssl.log;
  error_log /var/log/wss-error-ssl.log;

  server_name play.mysite.com www.play.mysite.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
  }

  location /websocket/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8443;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection "Upgrade";
   }

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on default_server; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl default_server; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/play.mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/play.mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  if ($host = www.play.mysite.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }


  if ($host = play.mysite.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name play.mysite.com www.play.mysite.com;
  return 404;
}
```

As you see, we have the subdomain on `https://play.mysite.com`. My `Express` server always listen on port `4000` and my `WebSocket` server listens to `wss` / port `8443` on production.

When I view the `/var/log/wss-error-ssl.log`, I get:

> 2018/03/01 04:45:17 [error] 30343#30343: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.117.172.118, server: play.mysite.com, request: "GET /static/css/app.67b8cb3fda61e1e2deaa067e29b52040.css HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:4000/static/css/app.67b8cb3fda61e1e2deaa067e29b52040.css", host: "play.mysite.com", referrer: "https://play.mysite.com/"

So, what exactly am I doing wrong?

The `proxy_pass` was set right. Listening to port `8443` for `WebSocket` on both client/server. What is the meaning? Thank you.

edit: and yes, I know the port `8443` is running:

```
root@MySITE:/var/www/play.mysite.com# netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:https                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:4000          *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8443               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*
udp        0      0 45.76.1.234.vultr.c:ntp *:*
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           *:*
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*
udp6       0      0 2001:19f0:5:2b9c:54:ntp [::]:*
udp6       0      0 fe80::5400:1ff:fe61:ntp [::]:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:ntp           [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*
```

Comment: You have several technical stacks here. Have you tried to connect WebSocket directly between your client and server before setting up nginx? Maybe you're missing a `proxy_redirect      http://localhost:4000 https://play.mysite.com;`. Finally, since you run **node.js**, why don't you try **socket.io**?

Comment: Try using a capital "U" in "upgrade" on this line:  `proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";`  Headers are case sensitive though *most* technologies treat them as insensitive...

Comment: Shouldn't you use `window.ws = new WebSocket(${tls}://${window.location.hostname}:${port}/websocket/);`

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed It is. Still - error.

Comment: I have rolled this question back because it was partially overwritten by the solution. If a question author has an answer they should write a self-answer, and not modify the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL'DR Add a second location block for `/websocket` and have the javascript client hit `wss://play.mysite.com/websocket`

I see a couple of issues with your nginx server conf.

1. Nginx is not listening on port `8443` yet your javascript is hitting `wss://play.mysite.com:8443`.  So while nginx is serving up ports `443` and `80` for the `play.mysite.com` domain, you javascript is trying to bypass nginx using `wss` (TLS) and hit NodeJS directly -- though I suppose you meant to offload the SSL onto Nginx.  The wss call must go through nginx in order for the SSL handshake to be successful.
2. You are passing all calls to `localhost:4000`.  Instead I suggest that you have two location blocks `location / { ... }` and `location /websocket { ... }`.  This way in the second websocket location block you can proxy pass the calls to `localhost:8443`.  This would require the client to connect to `wss://play.mysite.com/websocket`.

Comment: That makes sense. I did that and also upgraded the `Upgraded` variable. I updated my post with the new nginx `conf` file.. same error. I do believe. I also updated `client` side to connect to `new WebSocket('wss://play.mysite:8443/websocket')` and the `/var/log/wss-error-ssl.log` log.

Comment: The client side should not be using port 8443, try removing the `:8443` from the URL

Comment: The Nginx conf is basically saying:  "Proxy incoming connections on port 443 with a location matching `/websocket` to `localhost:8443`."  This is why we do not need to define the alternative port 8443 from the client.  Instead just let the wss protocol default to 443 -- the port nginx is listening on.

Comment: Also be sure to remove the trailing slash on the `location /websocket/ {` block.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. The client-side port was the problem. Adding a `upstream` as well. I edited my question to showcase the successfull nginx websocket secure with Vue project. Thank you!

Comment: Cool!  Glad we got it sorted.  Have fun with your project.

Comment: This is the first comment I've found after like 30+ other pages I've checked that explained it so I can actually fix my problem. I love you so much right now.

Comment: https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/x300/42754656/love-you-too-bro.jpg